# Преобразовать массив в переменную

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
// PHP
echo "<pre>";
print_r($for_x6_uyt);
echo "</pre>";

// HTML (PHP код дает на выходе)
Array
(
    [0] => маша
    [1] => лена
    [2] => оля
    [3] => юля
)
```

Из массива охота получить переменную, в которой все значения записаны через запятую. Что-то вроде:

```
// PHP
echo $devki;

// HTML    
маша,лена,оля,юля
```

В данный момент нагуглил "мсье" способ. Очень надеюсь, что это не единственное решение. В данный момент делаю так:

1. посчитать кол-во элементов массива;
2. в цикле приравнять к одной переменной ее + новый элемент;
3. поскольку в п.2. добавляется запятая в конец - обрезать последний символ.

Прошу подсказать, есть ли вариант быстрее, лучше?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$devkiString = implode(',',$devki);
print($devkiString);
```

Не надо ничего мудрить.

```
$glue = '_клей_'; //Строка, которой склеиваем элементы
$elements = array('маша','оля','ксюша'); // массив склеиваемых элементов

implode($glue,$elements);
```

вывод:

маша_клей_оля_клей_ксюша

Comment: Опередил на 25 сек)

Comment: Но опередил. =Ъ

Answer (score 7):

```
$arr = Array('маша','лена','оля','юля');

$strArr = implode(',',$arr);
```

Как видите все достаточно просто)

Comment: спасибо. все гениально и просто. плюсанул. жаль что "акцепт" нельзя поставить двоим. удивительно, как я пропустил эту функцию

Answer (score 2):

[implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

> Объединяет элементы массива в строку

Answer (score 2):

Ну дык:

```
$arr = array("1","2","3","4");
$str = implode(', ',$arr); 
echo($str);  // 1, 2, 3, 4
```