# Преобразовать массив в переменную с учетом ключей

Tags: php

Пока вы все тут, продолжение темы: [преобразовать массив в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119045/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E).

Народ, а есть ли расширенный вариант функции implode для ассоциативных массивов?

Например:

```
$cars = array('van'=>'volvo xc70','coupe'=>'mercedes clk gtr','suv'=>'nissan pathfinder');

$glue1 = '<br />';
$glue2 = ' - ';
extended_implode($glue1,$glue2,$cars);
```

Вывод:

```
van - volvo xc70<br />
coupe - mercedes clk gtr<br />
suv - nissan pathfinder<br />
```

N.B.:
Если штатной функции нет, лично мне алгоритм не нужен. =) Так что в этом случае вопрос меняется на "какие ошибки в моем способе".

```
function mb_extended_implode($glue1,$glue2,$elements,$enc='utf-8'){
  $out = '';
  foreach($elements as $key=>$value){
    $out .= $key.$glue2.$value.$glue1;
  }
  $out = mb_substr($out,0,mb_strlen($glue2,$enc),$enc);
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$res = array_map(function($k, $v) { return "$k - $v"; }, array_keys($cars), $cars);
echo implode('<br />', $res);
```

Или вот так, в зависимости от того, нужен `<br />` на конце или нет:

```
$res = array_map(function($k, $v) { return "$k - $v<br />"; }, array_keys($cars), $cars);
echo implode('', $res);
```

Comment: Хороший способ. Галочка. Примерно втрое быстрее моего. =)

Answer (score 4):

[http_build_query](http://ua.php.net/http_build_query)

> А вот это не подойдет ?

Comment: Вообще, очень близко. Настолько, что я даже поставлю плюсик и галочку. 
Скажем так: это способ нагляднее и проще, даже с учетом того, что, возможно, придется избавиться от URL-encode.

Comment: только плюсик: все-таки с результатом очень много возни: режутся пробелы, ставятся знаки равенства... Но сама по себе функция очень полезная.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что можно найти на сайте [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) :

```
    Here is a function to implode and array including the key and value pair.

<?php
/**
 * Implode an array with the key and value pair giving
 * a glue, a separator between pairs and the array
 * to implode.
 * @param string $glue The glue between key and value
 * @param string $separator Separator between pairs
 * @param array $array The array to implode
 * @return string The imploded array
 */
function array_implode( $glue, $separator, $array ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) return $array;
    $string = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if ( is_array( $val ) )
            $val = implode( ',', $val );
        $string[] = "{$key}{$glue}{$val}";

    }
    return implode( $separator, $string );

}
?>

You can, for example, encode an array to be sent as an URL query using this:
<?php
$query = url_encode( array_implode( '=', '&', $array ) );
?>

Or if you want to output an HTML element attributes:
<?php
echo '<input '.array_implode( '="', '" ', $array ).' />';
?>

Hope it can help someone!
```

Comment: Ну, я не вижу, если честно, существенных отличий от моего способа.

Comment: Да их и нету наверное особых, просто это с сайта мануала пхп - это видимо и есть расширенный вариант функции аля "оффициальный"

Answer (score 0):

Версия хорошая, но не полноценная.
Достаточно добавить рекурсию, и тогда полноценно многомерный массив будет парситься.

```
$val = array_implode( $glue, $separator, $val );
```

Вот так выглядит вся функция. Тут мы будем иметь и ключи и значения.

```
function array_implode( $glue, $separator, $array ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) return $array;
    $string = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if ( is_array( $val ) )
            $val = array_implode( $glue, $separator, $val );
        $string[] = "{$key}{$glue}{$val}";

    }
    return implode( $separator, $string );

}
```