# Область видимости анонимных функций.

Tags: php

[преобразовать массив в переменную с учетом ключей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/119081/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Вспоминаем, радуемся. Да, да, да. Снова я.
Итак:

```
function key_implode($array,$pattern='%s="%s"',$delimiter=' '){
    $res = array_map(function($k,$v) { global $pattern; return sprintf($pattern,$k,$v); }, array_keys($array), $array);
    return implode($delimiter, $res);
}
```

Какая область видимости у анонимных функций? Почему несмотря на глобал объявление $pattern не видится внутри анонимки? Что сделать, чтобы виделся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global $pattern` не работает, вероятно, потому что, `$pattern` находится в локальной области видимости.
Что бы `$pattern` был доступен внутри замыкания, необходимо использовать ключевое слово `use`:

```
function key_implode($array,$pattern='%s="%s"',$delimiter=' '){
    $res = array_map(function($k,$v) use ($pattern) { return sprintf($pattern,$k,$v); }, array_keys($array), $array);
    return implode($delimiter, $res);
}
```

Comment: "use" - ключевой зарезервированный оператор PHP? Странно, но в PHP5 он не работает....

Comment: [Замыкания](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) появились только в PHP 5.3. В более старых версиях работать, конечно же, не будет.

Comment: В общем, я и ожидал ответа от вас. Все же ваш кусочек кода. =)